# Are there any countries where the percentage of people who are vegetarian has significantly increased in recent years?

Tags: statistics, vegetarian-diet

Looking at [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_by_country), I see that the vegetarianism percentage within the general population varies a lot from country to country. My country (Romania) does not even appear in this list, and I could not find any reliable source about the percentage here (some believe to be about 1%).

[This discussion](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-eastern-europe-the-caucasus/romania/survival-as-vegetarian-in-romania) is both relevant and funny for the hardship of being a vegetarian in my native land. After joining the European Union, things have improved for vegetarians, but still many believe that "the best vegetable is pork".

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know of a country which has managed to increase the percentage of people who are vegetarian significantly in the recent period?
2. If yes, what were the key factors involved in achieving this?

Comment: Some relevant points can be found here: http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-is-the-rate-of-growth-of-veganism-and-vegetarianism-changing-over-time
I doubt you'll get a good answer for 2.

Comment: That is an interesting question. Basically, I am interested in a vegetarian increase success story and some of its key points. For example what I find plausible: raise red-meat consumption risks awareness, reduction of subsidies for meat industry etc.

Comment: I don't have the numbers, but here in Brazil, I'm definitely sure the number is increasing significantly. You notice that in the number of places that are adding vegan options, and in how often you hear about veganism. Also, [this link](http://www.svb.org.br/vegetarianismo1/mercado-vegetariano) shows a 10x increase in the number of google searches for "vegano" since 2012. Also note that this increase is definitely not related to any governamental programs, which are non-existent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Israel is becoming well known for it's very rapid rise in citizens choosing a vegan diet.

Numerous articles (see [this](http://www.timesofisrael.com/israel-the-promised-land-for-vegans/) and [this](http://www.thetower.org/article/how-israel-became-the-global-center-of-veganism/)) attempt to explain the reasons behind the rise:

As for your second question, it is tough to say what the best strategy might be. Although, for many people a religious conviction can certainly send them down this path. In general, the best way for someone like yourself to make a positive change is by asking for vegan and vegetarian food. The more people ask the more likely the market is to take notice. Education is next, show your friends videos like "earthlings", and "forks over knives", and see if exposure to this type of thing can help them make a change. Be aware though that it is not for everyone (yet) and you have to be patient. Attempting to force a vegan/vegetarian way of life on someone can lead to resentment if they are not ready.

Comment: This is an useful answer. Thanks.